# How can i add smileys in iPhone chat application

Tags: iphone

I've implemented a chat module in a social networking application for iPhone. But now we have to include smileys with the text message that we are sending. The text is displayed in a label in the Chat window. The binding of message is done with the following manner. While binding each messages, the following procedure is doing. An UIView is created, inside that an UiImageView is addsubviewed for loading bubble image, then inside the UIImageView, label is addsubviewed. That means message is finally displayed inside a label. But in the case of including smileys with the text message, is it possible to add smiley in the label. Now i had created a dictionary in the plist which include key for the image and image name. Can anybody have the solution for this task. Actually i 've been confused at loading smiley images along with text in the label. Hope anybody will give a nice solution for this issue.

Comment: Please reformat your question.  Lines indented by four spaces are perceived as code.

Comment: I wand to include emoticons with the text messages that i send through chat. The text messages are bind on a label. When i send emoticons with the text, how can i bind that emoticons on a label along with the text message. Hope you got me?